# Report Builder trouble with counting a sum of group values

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am trying to get the total field below to be the count of fields that are not calculated to equal 0. Instead of 1 I am looking for a total of 7 to display. The expression for the calculation of Column B is `Sum(Fields!Hours.Value)/40`. The expression for my Total field is: `SUM(IIF(Sum(Fields!Hours.Value)/40 <>0,1 ,0))`

```
 -Column A Column B -BA #1 1.175 -BA #2 1.04375 -BA #3 1.375 -BA #4 0 -BA #5 1.1125 -BA #6 1.0375 -BA #7 1.05 -BA #8 0 -BA #9 1.40625 -BA #10 0 -Total 1
```

---

I have tried and just do not know what I am doing wrong here. Any help please? Much appreciated!

Comment: sorry BA # is part of Column A and the number by it are part of Column B

Comment: you may update your question. Also you can use well-formatted code or screen shot to make your question more clear. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I might suggest trying to use the Column B textbox directly in your count expression.  Something like `SUM(IIF(ReportItems!ColumnBTextbox.Value), 1, 0)` would be my suggestion here.

Comment: Ty for response. When I try that I get this error message 'The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox17.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.' Any thoughts?